# Node JS Random events.js:72 throw er;

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know this has been raised a lot of times on here, other threads suggest that the port is already in use and that's why it crashes.

In this case, it's been running for days, using that port and will randomly crash with this error. It's had the port locked for days with no problems and is literally the only daemon on the server.

We're running on port 3000.

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: getaddrinfo ESRCH
   at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
   at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

Any help would be grateful

Comment: What environment are you running your app in?

Comment: What are the previous few lines before the `throw` statement?

Comment: @Andrius Centos 7 server

Comment: @atornblad that's all it presents other than that it's just a console log for a users username

Comment: No proxy, no docker stuff?

Comment: @Andrius Nope, nothing.